# Easy installation/removal of a LaTeX package

Tags: package-management, latex

I used to use LaTeX in Windows and there was Miktex Package Manager with which it was very easy to add a missing package. I wanted to install `textcomp` to Ubuntu 11.10 and it requires me to download the zip [from here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/obsolete/fonts/psfonts/ts1) and find the packages which are in `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex` in my case, extract the zip contents to there, and update the packages.

Is there a package manager which does installation and removal in an easier way like the Miktex Package Manager in Windows?

Comment: Since TeX Live in Ubuntu is outdated it might make sense to install TeX Live directly from upstream. Here's a guide: http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I advise to recur to an installation by hand of a tex package only when such tex package is not available in an ubuntu package.

Searching for it with

```
apt-file -x search '/textcomp.sty$'
```

I obtain the following results:

```
texlive-latex-base: /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
```

and it say the tex package you look for is contained in the ubuntu package whose name is `texlive-latex-base`, so install it, if not already installed.

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base
```

By the way, `apt-file` is a command to install separately contained in the `apt-file` package, and only a convenient and alternative way to search into the repositories the same way as http://packages.ubuntu.com/.

Comment: This is just great! I didn't know that all the packages I need were already in `texlive-latex-base` and `texlive-latex-extra`. Thanks.

Comment: My dear friend, after so much time looking, this was the easiest and fastest way that I was able to get some packages running! Kudos to you!

Comment: If you discover that you already have the package installed but it doesn't seem to work, remove it using apt-get and then install it again.  This worked for me for two different packages even though it said they were up to date.

Comment: +1 for teaching me about the apt-file utility.  I can't believe I'd never come across it before.